# Writing a tuple of character string with a specific range (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please can anyone help me with writing the correct code.
I am trying to create a tuple of character string that contains dates in the date range that Microsoft Excel supports, such as ("2013-Oct-17", "2100-01-01").

My code:

```
import time
import math


DAYS = ("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday")
FULL_MONTHS = ("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
"July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")


mm_ = tuple(str(date) for date in range(2013-oct-17, 2100-01-01))
print mm_
```

It gives me the following error when I run it (output):

```
mm_ = tuple(str(date) for date in range(2013-oct-17, 2100-01-01))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

Comment: You need to learn some basics of Python syntax first, I'm afraid.

Comment: The error is in this "range(2013-oct-17, 2100-01-01)", Python is interpreting this as 2013 minus the builtin function oct minus 17 and is saying that subtracting a function from an integer makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Using the third-party library [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) for recognition of different types of date strings and the builtin module [datetime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html). If one doesn't want to use dateutil, one can try all the possible formats with [datetime.datetime.strptime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) and use the one which works. One can remove `-timedelta(days=1)` if one wants to include the end date in the range.

```
from datetime import timedelta
from dateutil.parser import parse
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, DAILY

dates = tuple(str(dt.date()) for dt in rrule(DAILY, dtstart=parse("2013-oct-17"), until=parse("2100-01-01")-timedelta(days=1)))
print dates
```

**UPDATE**: Jon Clements the puppy has said in the comments about [dateutil.rrule.rrule](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-cf004ee9a75592797e076752b2a889c10f445418), updated code to utilize that. Thanks to him, it's now a neat four-liner.

Comment: If you're going to introduce another dependency, then at least make the most of it :) `from dateutil.rrule import rrule, DAILY; dts = tuple(rrule(DAILY, date(2012, 10, 1), until=date.today()))` for example

Comment: @JonClements oh thanks, I just saw dateutil through googling, I'll add your method to my post

Answer (score 0):

There are many libraries out there that will help you solve this problem.  The one I've found most useful is pandas.  Here is a snippet demonstrating how to solve your problem:

```
In [481]: import pandas as pd

In [482]: dates = pd.date_range('2013-10-17', '2100-01-01')

In [483]: mm_ = tuple(date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for date in dates)

In [484]: mm_[:5]
Out[484]: ('2013-10-17', '2013-10-18', '2013-10-19', '2013-10-20', '2013-10-21')
```

As noted in the comments, you have to input dates as strings.  If you want to have the date and month in long form, you can use:

```
In [486]: nn_ = tuple(date.strftime('%A %B %d, %Y') for date in dates)

In [487]: nn_[:5]
Out[487]: 
('Thursday October 17, 2013',
'Friday October 18, 2013',
'Saturday October 19, 2013',
'Sunday October 20, 2013',
'Monday October 21, 2013')
```

See the bottom of http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html for a list of which character codes refer to which date formats.